# How to format an external hard drive as UDF on a Mac

Tags: windows-7, macos, external-hard-drive, formatting, udf

I have an external USB hard drive that I'd like to format to UDF for cross-compatibility with Windows and Macs.  I tried exFAT, but for whatever reason, because of the block size (56KB) of the format, it's eaten up a huge portion of the disk space (~400GB actual data, ~900GB used disk space).

### Is there a utility on Mac OS X to format hard drives to UDF?

I can't find any built-in to my version (OS X 10.8.2), and `mkudffs` doesn't appear to be in my `$PATH`, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: OS X is supposed to fully support NTFS since Snow Leopard (fully updated), and anything newer. If I were you, I would go with that, unless you use Macs with older OS versions. Sounds simpler.

Comment: @Ariane It doesn't support writing to NTFS, only reading.

Comment: @Tyilo http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/02/enable-write-for-ntfs-hard-drives-on.html Looks like you need a third-party thingie.

Comment: @Ariane I'm aware of those products, however I wanted to point out that OS X doesn't support NTFS-writing out of the box.

Comment: @Tyilo Yeah, sorry. An article I'd read sort of implied that, but looks like I'd interpreted it wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Using the Terminal, you might be able to format a disk into UDF. I use the following command to format Blu-Ray-Disks:

```
newfs_udf -v "Untitled UDF" -r 2.60 /dev/diskX
```

You might want to first find out under what device name your actual disk is found.

Comment: I put it on [Github](https://github.com/ameenross/udfhd).

Comment: Revision 2.60 of UDF wastes space with an additional partition for metadata. This feature is useful to increase performance for DVD/BD media, but it is useless on hard disk and flash as it will reduce write performance. I recommend to use instead revision 2.01.

Comment: Not to mention that revisions > 2.01 [supposedly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format#Compatibility) cannot be mounted in read-write on Linux.

Comment: This works on my M1 MacBook Air running Mac OS 11.1 using a Pioneer BDR-XS07 drive. I can drag and drop files onto the disc from the Finder. Only problem is it is way slower than a flash drive.

Answer (score 4):

Someone did some research into how to format a flash drive with udf so it can be used on as many operating systems as possible. His findings are at http://sipa.ulyssis.org/2010/02/filesystems-for-portable-disks/ and there's a script to format the disk properly at http://sipa.ulyssis.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/udfhd.pl_.txt

Comment: is there an utility for windows to format a drive in udf like the perl script does?

Answer (score 0):

following project works just fine formatting any removable drive with UDF:

[format-udf](https://github.com/JElchison/format-udf)